# Inequalities across different Num types

Tags: haskell

How would I get the below code to work for comparing different numeric types?

```
foo::(Num a) => (Num b) => a -> b -> Bool
foo a b = (a == b)
```

I get error about deducing (a ~ b) from the context (Num a, Num b)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your type signature is syntactically wrong (according to my reading of [the context-free syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5) in the report, although GHC accepts it), it should be

```
foo::(Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> Bool
```

Regarding the question, you can't do that, `(<)` has type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, so both arguments must have the same type.

With a stronger restriction than just `Num`, you could for example have

```
bar :: (Real a, Real b) => a -> b -> Bool
bar a b = toRational a < toRational b
```

You need to be able to convert both arguments to the same target type (with a meaningful conversion) to compare the values. For types in the `Real` class, `toRational` provides such a conversion to a common target type (with the caveat that `toRational` doesn't work reasonably with NaNs and infinities if the starting type is a floating point type). `toInteger` would achieve the same for an `Integral` constraint.

There is no such common target type available with just a `Num` constraint.

For your special needs, you may be able to select a target type and define a

```
class Convertible a where
    toTarget :: a -> Target
```

if `Real` or `Integral` are not viable constraints.

Comment: Type signatures like `foo::(Num a) => (Num b) => a -> b -> Bool` are accepted by ghc. Don't know if it's actually against the report.

Comment: Never new that. By my reading of [the syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-810004.4.1) ([also here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5)), the report mandates there being only one `=>`. Probably the GHC parser handles it because it must handle multiple `=>` for higher-rank types.

Answer (score 4):

this should not be possible - as not every `Num` is comparable at all - say you even have

```
foo :: Num a => a -> b -> Bool
foo x y = x < y
```

and then use it for complex numbers what notion of `<` would you use? Lexicographic order is one option but it is not clear that it makes sense.

If you have two different numeric types, I ask you in return: "How would you compare complex numbers and reals? Or Hours, which can be made an instance of `Num` by using modulo calculation, with Minutes?"

If you used `Real a` as a constraint, you would have the `toRational` function - one way to solve that problem of comparability.

```
foo :: (Real a, Real b) => a -> b -> Bool
foo x y = x' < y'
        where x' = toRational x
              y' = toRational y
```